# Ordering : Ranges

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Denote selfadjoints:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):A=A^*\}$$

Note that one has:
$$\Delta A\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\langle\sigma(\Delta A)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(\Delta A)}$$

Introduce an ordering:
$$0\leq\Delta A:\iff\sigma(\Delta A)\geq0$$

Then one has:
$$A,A'\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):\quad 0\leq A\leq A'\iff\mathcal{R}A\subseteq\mathcal{R}A'$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication $0\leq A\leq B$ $\implies $ $\overline{\mathcal RA}\subset\overline{\mathcal RB}$ can be proven as follows. From $0\leq A\leq B$, we easily see that if $Bx=0$, then 
$$
0\leq\langle Ax,x\rangle\leq\langle Bx,x\rangle=0,
$$
so $A^{1/2}x=0$, and thus $Ax=0$. In other words, $\ker B\subset\ker A$. Then
$$
\overline{\mathcal RA}=(\ker A)^\perp\subset(\ker B)^\perp=\overline{\mathcal RB}.
$$

$$\ $$

The reverse implication does not hold. For instance, you can have 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\mathcal RA=\mathcal RB$, but 
$$
B-A=\begin{bmatrix}-2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not positive.

Comment: No. $\mathcal RB^\perp$ is the other axis. If $H=\mathbb C^2$ and $K=\{(a,0):\ a\in\mathbb C\}$, then $H\ominus K=\{(0,b):\ b\in\mathbb C\}$.

Comment: Sorry, it was I that misread your remarks.

Comment: I wrote a different argument for the first part. I'm not sure if the closures can be avoided.

Comment: Not my favourite topic.

Comment: Yep. I'll delete all mine.

Answer (score 1):

Although $0 \le A \le B$ implies $\overline{{\cal R}(A)} \subseteq \overline{{\cal R}(B)}$, it's **not** true without the closures.

For a counterexample, take $L^2[0,1]$.  Let $A$ be multiplication by $x$ (i.e. $A f(x) = x f(x)$), and $B = A + u u^*$ where $u(t) = t^{1/4}$ and $u^*$ is the corresponding linear functional, i.e.
$$ B f(x) = A f(x) + u^*(f) u(x) = x f(x) + x^{1/4} \int_0^1 t^{1/4} f(t)\; dt$$

Note that for any $f \in L^2[0,1]$, 
$$\int_0^\epsilon |A f(x)|\; dx \le \left( \int_0^\epsilon x^2\; dx\right)^{1/2} \|f\| = O(\epsilon^{3/2})$$
while $$ \int_0^\epsilon |u(x)|\; dx = \dfrac{4}{5} \epsilon^{5/4}$$
Since $\epsilon^{5/4} \ne O(\epsilon^{3/2})$, if $Af = B g$ we must have
$u^*(g) = 0$ so that $Bg = A g$, and then (since $A$ is one-to-one) $f=g$. 
That is, the only $f$ for which $Af \in {\mathcal R}(B)$ are those orthogonal to $u$.

EDIT: This was a bit more complicated than necessary.  Let
$A$ be any operator such that $A \ge 0$, $A$ is one-to-one and 
${\mathcal R}(A)$ is not all of $\mathcal H$ (the multiplication operator above is a good example).  Let $u \in {\mathcal H} \backslash {\mathcal R}(A)$, and take $B = A + u u^*$.  Then $A \le B$.  If $B x = A x + u^*(x) u \in {\mathcal R}(A)$, we must have $u^*(x) = 0$ and $B x = A x$.  Thus ${\mathcal R}(A) \cap {\mathcal R}(B) = A {\mathcal N}(u^*) \ne {\mathcal R}(A)$.